# r.horizon GRASS tool missing in QGIS list of GRASS tools

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I would like to run the r.horizon tool from GRASS in QGIS 3.4.4 but it does not show up in the list of GRASS tools in QGIS.  Is there some way to add it?

Comment: I am afraid some grass extensions will not show up due to the fact that they are pure C++ modules whilst the majority of the processing algorithm are pure python scripts.

Comment: The modules listed in the "Processing" tool have to be registered with a text file, see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description

Answer (score 1):

I have since found out that this tool can be accessed through the graphical modeler under GRASS tools even though it does not show up in the existing QGIS toolbox.  It can also be accessed using the R wrapper for QGIS, RQGIS3, which will allow us to do batch processing on a very large number of points.